# Print the test type in Python Nose

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I am using Python Nose and would like to print the type of the test ran, like whether it is a Doctest or unittest or so? How can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own plugin to change the printed name of the test.  Then, when you use the verbose flag the test type will print.  Try something like this:

```
from nose.plugins import Plugin
import doctest

class CustomName(Plugin):
    def describeTest(self, test):
        if isinstance(test, doctest.DocTestCase):
            return "Doctest: %s" % test
        else:
            return "Unittest: %s" % test
```

[After installing it](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/writing.html#registering), run it like:

```
nosetests --with-customname -sv test_directory
```

Be warned, this is untested.

Answer (score 1):

Using `--with-doctests` implies that you're running doctests. Anything outside of a doctest can be considered a unit test. AFAIK, they're not mutually exclusive, so you can't strictly tell which you're running if you've enabled `--with-doctests`.

Having said that, doctests generally *are* a form of unit test, so I'm not quite sure what end you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a way to run only either of doctests or unittests using Nose?

Comment: You can run nose on a specific file, effectively removing any externally defined unit tests.

Comment: You should also be able to limit the test type using the matching/nonmatching regex or using attribute matching.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little fragile. But note that nosetests are just on top of unittest

```
import inspect

def is_nose_test():
    assert "nose" in inspect.stack()[1][1]
```